# Why do these Tekton resources need to be in separate YAML files?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift

Does anyone know why putting these resources into a single file does not work, but having them in separate files work perfectly fine?

Running `oc apply -f big_file.yaml` on this does not work:

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerBinding
metadata:
  name: http-get-translater
spec:
  params:
  - name: placeholder
    value: nothing

apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: http-get-listener
spec:
  serviceAccountName: pipeline
  triggers:
    - name: http-get-trigger 
      bindings:
      - ref: http-get-translater
      template:
        ref: http-get-dispatcher

apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
metadata:
  name: http-get-dispatcher
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
  - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: PipelineRun
    metadata:
      generateName: http-get-run-by-listener
    spec:
      pipelineRef:
        name: http-get
```

But running `oc apply -f folder_with_resources_in_separate_files/` works.

I’ve tried changing the order of the resources within the file to see if it’s like a dependency issue, but could not get things working. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time